# Amount of samples question

Tags: probability

I need help finding the amount of samples needed in the following problem:

Assume I want to know the variation of the temperature during the day, so the population would be infinite because I can take samples every minute or every second and so on.

How do i find the required sample size to have a representative knowledge of the variation in the temperature? One sample every six hours may be too low and one sample every second may be too much, what is the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best answer", since it all depends on how precisely you want to follow the variations in temperature. However, there can be assumed to be some temporal interval $d t$ wherein the temperature function will be essentially linear, and you won't need a temporal solution higher than this. But then again, temperature is a statistical average, so it doesn't really make sense to demand too small a $dt$.

So all in all, your question is ill-defined; it all depends what you are intending to use the measurements for.

Comment: Well, suppose i want to view the variations during the day in a graph, then how many samples do i need?

Comment: 19. No, but seriously, I can't answer this (no one can, without knowing what you want to use your data for and what system you are making measurements on - for instance, how big variations in temp. there is during a day (and thus how many data points you need) depends hugely on where you are in the world). I'd suggest that you make as many measurements as you is able to do (for instance one every 10 min) and the look at the data plotted. Then you will probably see that the general tendency would not be lost if you took away some of the data points (say half of them). Then you have an estimate.